# ¿Cómo se usa la forma femenina de tema?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, género

He leído que la palabra *tema* se puede usar en la forma femenina: *la tema*. ¿Qué significa *la tema*, y cómo se usa? ¿Es común? ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre *el tema* y *la tema*?

Comment: +1 Nunca había escuchado "la tema"

Comment: ¿Donde leíste de eso?

Comment: @Flimzy: En otro foro, hablando de género, creo...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La [entrada para tema](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=tema)  en el Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas nos habla sobre el uso tanto en masculino como en femenino de tema, nos aclara en cuáles acepciones se usa en masculino y en cuáles en femenino y aporta un ejemplo de su uso en femenino:

> tema. En el español general culto, es voz masculina en la mayoría de
>   sus acepciones (‘asunto o materia’, ‘unidad de contenido de un libro o
>   una materia de estudio’, ‘fragmento de una obra musical sobre el que
>   se desarrolla una parte o toda la composición’, ‘canción’ y, en
>   gramática, ‘parte de la palabra sobre la que se añaden las
>   desinencias’): «Tal era el tema del libro recién leído» (Pitol Juegos
>   [Méx. 1982]); «Puentes está estructurada en un tema y cuatro
>   variaciones» (Melo Notas [Méx. 1990]); «Parodi cantó un tema propio»
>   (Clarín [Arg.] 19.5.97). **Con el sentido de ‘manía o idea fija en la
>   que alguien se obstina’, se ha usado tradicionalmente en femenino**: «Ya
>   le entró la tema de escandalizar por las recámaras» (VInclán Tirano
>   [Esp. 1927]); pero también se emplea en masculino, por contagio del
>   género propio del resto de las acepciones.

Answer (score 5):

Es correcto; "tema" se puede usar en femenino, con el significado de una idea fija u obsesiva. Mira los puntos 8 y 9 de la [entrada correspondiente](http://dle.rae.es/tema) en el diccionario de la RAE.

Según mi experiencia, este uso no es común en España. Sin embargo, en gallego existe "teima", también femenino y con el mismo significado de una idea fija u obsesiva, y es un vocablo muy común. Pero no es castellano, lo sé.